# Reading data from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to read data from a file line by line and push them back to a vector
The data is of the format
123 23 45
19 46 22
87 26 31

The program gives no output and an error code of 11.

```
std::vector<int>* readDataFromFile(std::string path){


    std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>;
    int a, b, c;
    std::ifstream inputStream;
    inputStream.open(path);
    while(inputStream>>a>>b){
        v->push_back(a);
        v->push_back(b);
        v->push_back(c);
    }
    inputStream.close();

}

int main() {

    std::vector<int>* v = readDataFromFile("file1.txt");
    for(auto it= v->begin(); it != v->end(); it++){
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the same directory the program is running?

Comment: Yup it is in the same directory.

Comment: You should check if the `inputStream.is_open()`.  Also you never take in `c` in `while(inputStream>>a>>b)`

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement in `readDataFromFile`.

Comment: That was gross, the return statement and the c did it. Apologies.

Comment: Don't forget to delete your vector created with `new`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't forget to read c in the loop:

   ```
   while(inputStream>>a>>b>>c) {
       v->push_back(a);
       v->push_back(b);
       v->push_back(c);
   }
   ```
2. You are allocating a std::vector dynamically and never deleting it. Instead return the vector by value.
3. And also the call to fstream::close is not necessary, the stream is closed from fstream's destructor when it goes out of scope.
4. In general it is better to pass read-only string parameters by const reference.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <vector>

   std::vector<int> readDataFromFile(const std::string& path){
     std::vector<int> v;
     int a, b, c;
     std::ifstream inputStream(path);
     while(inputStream>>a>>b>>c){
         v.push_back(a);
         v.push_back(b);
         v.push_back(c);
     }

     return v;
   }

   int main() {
     std::vector<int> v = readDataFromFile("file1.txt");
     for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
         std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
     }

     return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: It is worth noting that returning an `std::vector` by value may copy the entire vector, depending on the optimizations the compiler is able to perform.

Comment: This is true, but it is a common practice to return vectors by value and rely on RVO (or in C++11 move semantics). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247654/returning-stdvector-by-value