# std::vector, std::string; will it move?

Tags: c++11, stdvector

```
std::vector<int> myvec(){
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // do some push_back's

  return myvector;
}

std::string mystr(){
  std::string mystring = "hello";

  return mystring;
}

std::vector<int> myvector = myvec();
std::string mystring = mystr();
```

Will it move? Or will it be copied by value?

Do not have anything else to say, but have to fulfil the requirement of writing more. Hence I am writing down some more text for you, folks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning std::vector by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247654/returning-stdvector-by-value)

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ ISO standard, The compiler is allowed either to copy it, move it , or allocate it on the caller and avoid copying/moving altogether.

Most likely most of the compilers (GCC, Clang, VC++) will choose the third option (allocate it on the caller - Return Value Optimization) with optimizations turned on.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your version of C++, but in modern C++ there is a promise that returning an std:vector is efficient and doesn't cause an element-by-element copy operation.

Comment: Don't say modern C++. Say what standard version and ideally back it up with a reference or quote.