# Should function local variables always be returned with std::move?

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, return-value, move-semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using std::move() when returning a value from a function to avoid to copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817873/using-stdmove-when-returning-a-value-from-a-function-to-avoid-to-copy)

Assume you have any sort of variable inside a function and you want to return it:

```
X foo(/*...*/) {
  X x;
  //...
  return x;
}
```

I'm trying to determine if there is any case where `return std::move(x);` would be problematic. Clearly `x` will go out of scope, so there doesn't seem to be a good reason to keep it around. However, I'm not sure what the effects would be if `X` was some `Y&` referencing some long(er) lived variable.

Comment: `return std::move(x);` inhibits NRVO. Don't use it unless you have to.

Comment: And if the compiler doesn't do NRVO, it will automatically move the variable if it can because `x` is an xvalue.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9532608/500104)'s answer for the relevant standard quote.